# How to get a prefilled authorization key in swagger with drf-specatular

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I use django, drf and drf-spectacular. I create swagger documentation.
Some endpoints require authentication.
I can authenticate in swagger by pressing authorize and filling in the token.

I would like that this filled in automatically for me.
How do I do that?

I tried to add preauthorizeApiKey to my settings, like this:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
        'preauthorizeApiKey': 'Token my-secret-token'
    }
}
```

It doesnt work.